# I want to hide a ID when specific parameter is in URL (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, hide

I want to hide an ID named #ko when a specific parameter is found in the url.

**---Example---**

For example this is the thank you page when a customer send a question:

```
https://website.nl/bedankt?k=Vraag&n1=Your%20Name&n2=&n3=
```

I want to hide id="ko" when k=Vraag is in the URL

But when the a customer asked for a quotation (k=Offerte) I want to show id="ko".

```
https://website.nl/bedankt?k=Offerte&n1=Your%20Name&n2=&n3=
```

This is the html:

```
<span style="color: #ffffff;">Ik heb je bericht in goede orde ontvangen en zal binnen 48 uur een reactie geven op je <span class="keuze">[get_param param="k"]</span><span id="ko"> aanvraag</span>.</span>
```

---

This is what I got right now, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf("k=Vraag") != -1) {
      $("#ko").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Please provide the html.

Comment: The javascript is loaded in the footer

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the "*[mcve]*" code *here* in your question; questions should be self-contained and persist beyond the time it takes you to fix your code. See: "*[I've been told to create a 'runnable' example...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/82548)*" for guidance as to how to create a code snippet.

Comment: On the website you pointed at, `window.location.href.indexOf("k=Vraag")` returns `32`. So, `$("#ko")` should be hidden. It's not, so, there's something else in your code that prevents it from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work assuming jQuery is loaded (it was not)  but I suggest you use searchParams and a toggle

```js
$(function() {
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  const keuze = url.searchParams.get("k");
  $(".keuze").toggle(keuze === "" || keuze === "Vraag");
  $("#ko").toggle(keuze !== "Vraag" && keuze !== "Offerte");
});
```

Plain JS

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  const keuze = url.searchParams.get("k");
  document.querySelector(".keuze").hidden = keuze && keuze !== "Vraag";
  document.getElementById("ko").hidden = keuze === "Vraag" || keuze === "Offerte";
});
```

My second code after running the active code in the console shows

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work either. Is it better to understand if I give an example in english on my website?

Comment: Ik spreek vloeiend Nederlands

Comment: Alright, good to know. Let me take a look again.

Comment: Thats weird, I have replaced your code but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241726/discussion-between-max-and-mplungjan).

Comment: Updated to handle offerte